# Price product page more than 2 decimals occasionally, how to change to 2 decimals?

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

We use Prestashop 1.6 for some time now and we noticed some errors in Google merchant, especially with products that have discounts.

How can we change product.tpl so it always shows a price with 2 decimals. Google merchant misreads prices with more that 2 digits.

Examples:

```
<span id="our_price_display" class="price" itemprop="price" content="4.2075">€ 4,21</span> incl. BTW<meta itemprop="priceCurrency" content="EUR" /></p><p id="reduction_percent" ><span id="reduction_percent_display">-15%</span></p><p id="reduction_amount" style="display:none"><span id="reduction_amount_display"></span></p><p id="old_price"><span id="old_price_display"><span class="price">€ 4,95</span>

<span id="our_price_display" class="price" itemprop="price" content="2.4">€ 2,40</span> incl. BTW<meta itemprop="priceCurrency" content="EUR" /></p><p id="reduction_percent" style="display:none;"><span id="reduction_percent_display"></span></p><p id="reduction_amount" style="display:none"><span id="reduction_amount_display"></span></p><p id="old_price" class="hidden"><span id="old_price_display"><span class="price"></span>
```